# Add protocol to href value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have added an editor and user can enter anything they want, then I show that entered text under message card, so if user has entered a link like `Click here` & its HTML part is `<a href="google.com">Click here</a>` so when show this under message card and click on click here then its not redirecting to google.com it goes to `http://my-website.com/google.com`, its because href value don't have any protocol, so how I can add protocol to its value and there could be multiple links in single message, some could have protocol and some not.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Comment: use this http://www.google.com  instead of google.com.full url should be

Comment: Guys I think you didn't get my question, imagine you have added TinyMCE editor in your site & you are allowing user to enter content for their blog and once saved that content will be shown in blog section, so in their content if they have inserted something like `<a href="google.com">click here</a>` and if any user clicks on it, it won't redirect to google.com

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop over the `<a>` links after you have added the HTML from editor to your message card and check the protocol of each anchor link. If there is no protocol then add one to them.

```
$('#messageCard').find('a').each(function() {
    //get the href value of each anchor element
    var hrefValue = $(this).attr('href');
    //use regular expression to check if the href contain http:// or    
    //https://. If not then add http://
    if (!hrefValue.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+:\/\//))
       {
          $(this).attr('href','http://' + hrefValue);
       }
});
```

Comment: why http and not https :p

Comment: editor gives output as a string so thats not really in DOM its like `"<p>test <a href="google.com">click here</a>"`

Comment: I mean after you append this html in your message card.

Comment: but I think it will give performance issue, because there could be 1000s of messages in message card, so its good idea to update the text before it saved

Comment: You can do the same on saving the HTML from the editor.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a nice idea to let user to enter HTML code in the editor. But if you insist to do so, you may try

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).attr("href").startsWith("http")) {
      $(this).attr("href", "http://" + $(this).attr("href"));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="google.com">Click here</a>
```

Comment: actually I am not allowing, its the editor which create whole code in background and send to backend